# Why are there two standards for accessing environment variables in Windows when they call point to the same environment variables?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, environment-variables

I can use `$env:<env-name>` in Powershell to access an environment variable, and in `cmd` and all other parts of Windows I can use `%env-name%` to access them.

Why is are there two different standards for this if we're only using one operating system?

Comment: There aren't two different "standards" persay.. they are two different interpreters.  I assure you "All other parts of windows" is not correct.  If you look at the actual API being invoked.. for windows it is `GetEnvironmentVariable()` it doesn't use any of this nonsense.  The scripting language (in this case batch/powershell), the authors have chosen to use different delineation to access these variables.. under the hood, I assure you, it is the same `GetEnvironmentVariable()` function call.  You will find that Perl, Python, Bash.. and other languages running on Windows have their own way.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I guess I wasn’t thinking of PowerShell as separate from Windows, since for the majority of its’ history it has been a Windows only scripting language.   But now it run on Linux too (heaven help us).

Comment: TOTALLY understood! :)  Microsoft hired some Xnix programmers to come up with this language (powershell) because one must admit.. Xnix rules the command line.  That is why it looks so Perl like.. even if it *does* use the .net framework.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas What prompted this question in the first place was that I already knew the %% syntax, but was for some reason annoyed that I couldn’t type an additional four characters instead of two in the $env: syntax.  But that’s dumb.  Why would I want to do that; in the same vein why would a bunch of *nix program something on win32?  Traitors!  Well maybe not...PowerShell isn’t as bad as I though but compared to Perl you have to type a lot; sorta like COBOL, but they do have some shortcuts none of them being passed arguments.

Comment: OMG leeand00.. you cracked me up.. apparently you TOO are wise ;) SO STUPID.. agreed.  Power to the `@_` (which I hated in Perl and still do)

Comment: @leeand00 - PowerShell isn't actually separate from Windows.  It has been installed out of the box for more than a decade.  It was installed by default on Windows 7 and was an optional feature for Windows Vista.  As for the reason the syntax is different, PowerShell is .NET, so much of the syntax is due to the fact it's a programming language itself vs a scripting language.  If you can do it with a command prompt .NET application you can probably do it with PowerShell.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of the question. How does knowing why the syntax is different make any difference?

Answer (score 3):

CMD and Powershell are different technologies from different eras. Most of the CMD syntax rules go back to the '80s.

Powershell is an entirely different shell designed to compete with an entirely different class of software ( ie bash). as such, it needs a more sophisticated syntax, and MS took the opportunity to implement one, both for efficiency, and to give PS a particular "flavor", just like every other major shell.

you might as well ask why python and c# use different syntax.

Comment: This is a good answer.. but "from different eras" has nothing to do with it.  It was the choice the dev writing the interpreter chose.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, completely true. I guess when you have been around as long as I have, you start to see paradigms come and go, and its not uncommon for me to see something and say "that's very 2005...". in the end, what we expect from technology has evolved in a rather linear fashion, so design requirements and expectations have evolved in the same manner. this is primarily what drives the difference s when comparing very legacy technology like the vdm with modern (very active) technology like PS.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I have been writing commercial code (windows too) since 1993.. but yes.. I get what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

While in CMD you are really *just* accessing the environment variables, in PowerShell, you are working with a whole Environment drive. There is a lot more logic behind it, which gives you more opportunities and more flexibility. You can read more about environment variables in PowerShell [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_provider) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables). Just some examples:

The Environment drive `Env` is listed besides all other drives. Execute the following cmdlet to see it:

```
Get-PSDrive
```

You can access this drive (mostly) like you access a FileSystem drive. For example, you can list all environment variables by executing:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

You can also get a particular environment variable by executing:

```
Get-Item Env:TMP
```

To just get the value, you can execute:

```
(Get-Item Env:TMP).Value
```

or (as you already did):

```
$Env:TMP
```

So, PowerShell uses a whole different technology to work with environment variables. That's why it uses a different syntax, which is [defined](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7#using-and-changing-environment-variables) as follows btw.:

> `$Env:TMP`
>
> In this syntax, the dollar sign (`$`) indicates a variable, and the drive name (`Env:`) indicates an environment variable followed by the variable name (`TMP`).